# Doctrine-CLI database creation issue

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine

I have Doctrine setup in my Zend Framework application and I built my schema YAML file. But when I tell Doctrine to build the tables it says it does but it doesn't actually make them. It creates the models, and will create the DB but it will not populate the DB with the tables and throws no errors. Does anyone have a guess or know why this is not working?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I had a model I created for testing already in the folder. Evidentially Doctrine thought that was a bad idea and then didn't make the tables in the DB.